# How to detect if the MySQL service (or simply MySQL) is available with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, service

How can I do that? like:

```
if (mysql is available) {
   connect and do queries
}
else {
   use files
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "a MySQL connection is available" or "the MySQL extension is available"?

Comment: What are you trying to test? If PHP is built with MySQL support? If you can connect to a MySQL server? If you can connect and authenticate with a MySQL server?

Comment: Do you want to know if the MySQL module is installed and available to PHP?  Or, are you wanting to know if you were able to successfully connect to the MySQL server?

Answer (score 4):

Not that elegant:

```
if (shell_exec('mysql -V') != ''){
  echo "MySql is here";
}else{
  echo "No MySql here";
}
```

You may search for mysql in the string that "shell_exec('mysql -V')" will return.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

`extension_loaded("mysql");`

http://us.php.net/extension_loaded

Comment: Nope, that won't work. I've just stopped MySQL on my development machine and PHP still returns 1 for extension_loaded("mysql").

Answer (score 2):

I can't test this, but

```
if (function_exists('mysql_connect'))
```

may work.

Answer (score 1):

Or use the phpinfo() function and search "mysql" with CTRL+F and check if the extension is activated...

Answer (score 0):

Just try to connect and if fail then do other thing.

***eg:***

```
if ($link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')) {
    //do queries
} else {
   //use files
}
```

Comment: Won't that throw a fatal error if there is no MySQL module loaded?

Comment: @Jonathan The op wants to test mysql is available or not, not whether the mysql module is loaded.

Comment: I guess I thought they were asking if MySQL was installed on the system and available to use, i.e. loaded in php.

Comment: @Xdazz I must confess that I read the OP in the same was as Jonathan - both answers could be correct.